# OLS Intercept is Sample Averages?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, least-squares, linear-regression

I'm having trouble with some of these lecture notes deriving a property of OLS, such that, if the relation has an intercept, then $$\bar{y}=\bar{x}^{\prime} \hat{\beta}$$ with
$$
\bar{x}=\left[\begin{array}{c}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i 0}(=1) \\ \vdots \\ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i K}\end{array}\right]
$$
the (K + 1) x 1 vector of sample means of the independent variables.

Proof: Partition X as
$$
X=\left[\begin{array}{llll}\iota & x_{1} & \cdots & x_{K}\end{array}\right]
$$
then normal equations can be written as:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}\iota^{\prime} \\ x_{1}^{\prime} \\ \vdots \\ x_{K}^{\prime}\end{array}\right] X \hat{\beta}=\left[\begin{array}{c}\iota^{\prime} \\ x_{1}^{\prime} \\ \vdots \\ x_{K}^{\prime}\end{array}\right] y
$$

The first equation is $$\iota^{\prime} X \hat{\beta}=\iota^{\prime} y$$ or
$$
\frac{1}{n} \iota^{\prime} X \hat{\beta}=\frac{1}{n} \iota^{\prime} y
$$
or
$$
\bar{x}^{\prime} \hat{\beta}=\bar{y}
$$

Here we use
$$
\frac{1}{n} \iota^{\prime} X=\frac{1}{n} \iota^{\prime}\left[\begin{array}{llll}\iota & x_{1} & \cdots & x_{K}\end{array}\right]=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}\frac{1}{n} \iota^{\prime} \iota & \frac{1}{n} \iota^{\prime} x_{1} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n} \iota^{\prime} x_{K}\end{array}\right)
$$
and e.g.
$$
\frac{1}{n} \iota^{\prime} x_{1}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i 1}=\bar{x}_{1}
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{1}{n} \iota^{\prime} X=\bar{x}^{\prime}
$$
Row vector of sample means of the columns of X.

**Q:** I actually follow the proof all the way to $\frac{1}{n} \iota^{\prime} x_{1}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i 1}=\bar{x}_{1}$.  But we're dealing with scalars here since he's only looking at the first row. I don't see where he's able to get the summation. I only see an average if $\iota^{\prime}$ is a row of 1's.

Comment: $\iota$ is a column vector of 1's, so $\iota '$ is in fact a row of 1's. The first column of $X$ is a column of 1's to calculate the intercept, the first element $\hat{\beta}_0$ of the vector $\hat{\beta}$ in $\hat{y}=X\hat{\beta}$.

Comment: @AmaanM but the proof takes out the first equation of the system with $\imath^{\prime} X \hat{\beta}=\imath^{\prime} y$.  This is what's confusing me. If it's the first equation of the matrix, $\iota = 1$ and you get $\frac{y}{n}$ without summation and not average

Comment: He never limits $\iota$ to a single element, it's always a vector in each step, so $\iota '$ is a row. When he refers to the first equation being $\iota ' X\hat{\beta} = \iota ' y$, it's still an entire row vector there, not just a single 1.